# How to change Matlab settings (for history.m) in terminal?

Tags: matlab, terminal, history

I am using Matlab on a remote server from my MacBook. Partly because I find the Matlab GUI clunky under X11, I use it in the terminal window (by running `matlab -nodesktop`). This has been working fine, until I now needed to copy some stuff from the command history.

It seems like history.m is only being saved on exit, even though when I check the settings in the GUI, it says that it is being saved for each command. It also seems like `exit` statements are included in history.m when Matlab is run from terminal, but not in the GUI, so it seems like the settings in the GUI don't apply there. I cannot find anything in the Matlab help pages on how to change the settings for the terminal window.

I need to access the command history for my session while it is still open. Does anybody have an idea about how I can do this -- short of starting to use the GUI?

Comment: Which version of Matlab are you using? The GUI hasn't been based on X11 since 2009a, if I recall correctly.

Comment: True. But note that I am running Matlab on a remote server (through ssh). That's why I am still stuck with X11 -- unless you know something I don't.

Comment: (I quite like the native GUI, BTW, and I use it as much as I can. But whenever I'm doing things on big data, I need more computing power than my MacBook has, and then I have to ssh. It would be great if Matlab allowed you to access another machine through its interface, but unless it unbeknownst to me does, that's another discussion ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might try the diary function. It logs both commands and their (text based) results to a file. On my system (Mac OSX with MATLAB R2011b), the output does not show up in the diary file immediately, but it does update when you turn off the diary. Which you can do repeatedly if you need without exiting matlab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yes, that is a possibility. I was aware of this, though, and the reason why I am still looking for something else is that it's a lot less convenient to copy commands from the diary, mainly because of all the output that it prints in addition to your commands.